# if condition is not working properly it is not checking properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a function to create automatic username on the bassis of name if name already exist then username will be creted on the basis of user id but when I created a user and tested if the name is already not present into the database it is creating username alongwith user id as it shouldn't be because test name is not already in the database. here is my code

```
// $user_id is the last inserted id
$check_username = $this->db->where('name', $name);
        $check_username = $this->db->where('id !=', $user_id);
        $check_username = $this->db->get('users');

        if($check_username >= 1) {
            $username = strtolower(str_replace(" ", ".", $name)) . $user_id;
        } else {
            $username = strtolower(str_replace(" ", ".", $name));
        }

        $this->db->where('id', $user_id);
        $this->db->update('users', array("username" => $username));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$this->db->num_rows()` to check whether name is already present in database or not like belw:

```
$this->db->where('name', $name);
$this->db->where('id !=', $user_id);
$check_username = $this->db->get('users');

if($this->db->num_rows($check_username) >= 1) {
    $username = strtolower(str_replace(" ", ".", $name)) . $user_id;
} else {
    $username = strtolower(str_replace(" ", ".", $name));
}

$this->db->where('id', $user_id);
$this->db->update('users', array("username" => $username));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help it really helped me out

Comment: glad to help.Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->db->count_all_results()`

```
$check_username = $this->db->where('name', $name);
    $check_username = $this->db->where('id !=', $user_id);
    $check_username = $this->db->get('users');

    if($this->db->count_all_results() >= 1) {
        $username = strtolower(str_replace(" ", ".", $name)) . $user_id;
    } else {
        $username = strtolower(str_replace(" ", ".", $name));
    }

    $this->db->where('id', $user_id);
    $this->db->update('users', array("username" => $username));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$this->db->num_rows()` or try below code

```
$check_username = $this->db->where('name', $name)->where('id !=', $user_id)->get('users')->num_rows();

if($check_username > 0) {
    $username = strtolower(str_replace(" ", ".", $name)) . $user_id;
} else {
    $username = strtolower(str_replace(" ", ".", $name));
}

$this->db->where('id', $user_id);
$this->db->update('users', array("username" => $username));
```